# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer aws lambda typescript

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, curl, aws-lambda

I have a small app (just testing it out for now) written in typescript and I would like to deploy to lambda. I have followed the official tutorial for [creating lambda container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) in AWS official guide. I have only changed the location of the handler to `src/index.ts`

When I run `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'` I get `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "dist/index.handler" ]
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "yarn run build && node dist/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "14",
    "jest": "^27.4.5"
  }
}
```

*src/index.ts*

```js
export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("It ran");

  return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    message: "Hello",
    body: "Hello"
  })
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}
```

From my understanding AWS container images uses [aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator). Visiting their github page theres literally nothing regarding debugging. No way to get the logs, no way to understand what is running or not.

From this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/769583/330127) it looks like that the app inside the container doesn't have a port assigned to it, but then again, no way to debug or see logs.

When I deploy the function to aws lambda and test it, it works as expected:

[image]

### Question

How can I debug what is going on? Why am I receiving a `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that when building the image I mapped port `9000` to `8000` when the container application binds to `8080`. It solved the issue by changing:

```
docker run -p 9000:8000 xxxx
```

to

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 xxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

If after following the accepted answer and still getting the error. Just make sure you don't have another container running on port 9000.

Just run `docker container ls` and check if PORTS column does not contain 9000 for another container.

To fix it just choose another port that you know is not being used for example
`docker run -p 9001:8080 xxxx` and update your curl request accordingly